# How to write the whole array of information into a file?

Tags: php

The script outputs a list and must write the entire list to a file. Why does the script write only the last line to the .txt file, and not the entire list? How do I fix a script to write the entire list to a .txt  file?

```
     $dir = "./radio/radio_stantion/";
    $name = scandir($dir);
    for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {

    $fopen=file( $dir.$name[$i] );
    $line = $fopen[3];
    $url = $fopen[2];
    $radio_name = explode(") ", $line);
    $radio_url = explode("//", $url);
    $link = $radio_url[1];
    $http = explode(":", $link);
    $fff = $http[1];
    $port = explode("/", $fff);
    $zzz = $radio_name[1];
    $finalname = preg_replace ("/[^a-zа-я\s]/si","",$zzz);
    $sss = $finalname."-".$http[0]."-".$port[0];
    --------------------------    
    A list is displayed:
    FRESH FM IBADAN    s4.voscast.com 8442 
    Bestfriend FM     178.32.62.172   8217
    COOLfahrenheit    111.223.51.7    8005 
    RThess            37.59.32.115    6156
    SmoothJazzcom     149.56.155.209  80


    --------------------------
        $f = fopen("../top_100/radio_top_100_v2.txt", "w");
        fwrite($f, $sss); 
        fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Try fopen("../top_100/radio_top_100_v2.txt", "a"); You're overwriting the previous line.

Comment: You code is incomplete.

Comment: @JazzCat You're right. Recorded the entire array of information in a file.

Comment: @Sergey_777 That's a pretty lazy fix.

Comment: No, all the same, not that. The script writes the list completely, but the next time it adds a new one and the list in the text file increases. So it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I barely understand whats going on there but the problem is that you are opening the file in write mode on each loop iteration.

Using `fopen` with `w` mode clears the file and writes to it:

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

You should `fopen` the file before the loop. `fwrite` on each iteration. and `fclose` after the loop.

```
$f = fopen("../top_100/radio_top_100_v2.txt", "w");
for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
    ...
    fwrite($f, $sss); 
    ...
}
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overwriting the previous writes in every iteration. Try writing everything to a string variable first(and append a `\n` to each line), then write the string contents to the file one time. If you are dealing with a lot of data, then it would make sense to use `fwrite` every iteration, so not to consume too much memory.

File IO is expensive, so only opening the file once, and writing once, should improve performance as well.